# How to alias ruby as jruby in Windows

Tags: ruby, batch-file, jruby, default

I have installed jruby 1.6.3 on Windows 7 and to use jruby from command line I use command `jruby`, example:

```
jruby -v
```

but some script want to use command *ruby*.
How to alias `ruby` as `jruby`. I tried to use `doskey` in bat but it doesn't work.
I tried to create bat file:

```
@"jruby.bat" %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9
```

but it doesnt work too.

Answer (score 1):

It seems JRuby loader, which is based on Netbeans one ([announced here](http://blog.emptyway.com/2009/10/17/native-jruby-launcher-for-windows/)) is sending `argv[0]` when starting the loader, as shown in the following code:

https://github.com/vvs/jruby-launcher/blob/master/jrubyexe.cpp#L78
https://github.com/vvs/jruby-launcher/blob/master/nbexecloader.h#L20

Because of that, `ruby` is send to JRuby DLL entry point and is failing to load the platform:

```
> ruby -v
jruby: No such file or directory -- ruby (LoadError)
```

`argv[0]` is required because JRuby on Windows support both `jruby` and `jrubyw` launchers.

I suggest you ask this specific feature request at [JRuby bug tracker](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JRUBY)

**EDIT:** answer below was based on the assumption that jruby.exe hardcoded the entry point to load jruby.dll, seems it not.

JRuby on Windows uses `jruby.exe` as executable instead of the batch file (the batch file is kept for compatibility)

You can simply `copy jruby.exe ruby.exe` inside JRuby's bin directory.

Please note that if by chance you have another Ruby in the `PATH` this will definitely bork it.

If you need to switch between multiple Ruby interpreters you can use Pik, is a [Ruby Version Manager for Windows](https://github.com/vertiginous/pik).

Hope that helps.

Comment: It doesn't work. When I test it by 'ruby -v' it gives me an error: 'jruby: No such file or directory -- ruby (LoadError)'

Comment: Ah, problem lies in the launcher code, is sending "ruby" to NBLauncher: https://github.com/vvs/jruby-launcher/blob/master/jrubyexe.cpp#L78 and https://github.com/vvs/jruby-launcher/blob/master/nbexecloader.h#L20, will recommend you open a feature request at JRuby bug tracker http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JRUBY